# /gazebo/get_model_state in ROS2 not present

Tags: ros-foxy, gazebo-11

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I want to extract with a python script the position of a robot (that I know the model name of) from gazebo.

In many forum posts and tutorials for ROS1, the `/gazebo/get_model_state` service ([API docu](http://docs.ros.org/en/api/gazebo_msgs/html/srv/GetModelState.html)) is used for that, but as mentioned [here](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/wiki/ROS-2-Migration:-Entity-states) it is deprecated.

What I have done so far is following [this](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Writing-A-Simple-Py-Service-And-Client.html) tutorial and now want to use it to get the position of a turtlebot3 inside its demo world.

If I put `ros2 service call /get_entity_state gazebo_msgs/GetEntityState '{name: turtlebot3, reference_frame: world}'`
the output is just:

```
waiting for service to become available...
```

Does that mean, /get_entity_state is not running automatically when gazebo is started?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28323//gazebo/get_model_state-in-ros2-not-present/) by [Zeckurbo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/36410/zeckurbo/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 64 on 2022-07-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

As I found out [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/360161/ros2-dashing-service-get_entity_state-is-missing/),
if you want to use get_model_state, you can simply add

```
<plugin name="gazebo_ros_state" filename="libgazebo_ros_state.so">
      <ros>
        <namespace>/gazebo</namespace>
      </ros>

      <update_rate>1.0</update_rate>
    </plugin>
```

to the world file of your ros2 package.
To test it, you can run

```
ros2 service call /gazebo/get_entity_state gazebo_msgs/GetEntityState '{name: my_robot_name, reference_frame: world}'
```

when gazebo is running in the background, and the service appears on `ros2 service list`

---

Originally posted by [Zeckurbo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/36410/zeckurbo/) with karma: 64 on 2022-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0