# how get the depth of the underwater vihicle (uuv) in gazebo-garden?

Tags: gazebo

I'm currently working on simulating an unmanned surface vehicle (USV) using Gazebo Garden. Specifically, I'm using the LRAUV Simulation model. My goal is to obtain the 6 degrees of freedom (6-DOF) data of the USV within a ROS2 node.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance on how to achieve this integration. If anyone has experience or insights into connecting Gazebo Garden with ROS2 for the LRAUV Simulation model, I'd be grateful for your assistance.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you looking for Ground Truth from the simulation, or for something that can also give the answer on a real robot?

Comment: Thanks for asking , I would like to implement it in the simulation.

Comment: Please edit your post to explain from where you need this information: from inside another gazebo plugin, from inside a ros2 node, from the terminal command line? The method is different depending on the environment you access gazebo-garden from.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I have updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach for gazebo-ignition is:

1. in gazebo, install the `get_entity_state` plugin that creates a ros2 service which will provide the state of a gazebo-model. The plugin filename is `libgazebo_ros_state.so` (I think from the `gazebo_ros` package.)
2. in your ros2 node, make a ros2 service call to `/gazebo/get_entity_state` with the args set to the proper values. You will get back a message with the object's current pose & twist.

This plugin is discussed in [Ques1](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/29310/gazebo-get-model-state-in-ros2-not-present) and [Ques2](https://answers.ros.org/question/360161/ros2-dashing-service-get_entity_state-is-missing/).

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment~I found that install the get_entity_state plugin didn't work for me. So I change the Gazebo version to Homonic.