# reset robot position using "/gazebo_msgs/srv/SetModelState"

Tags: gazebo, ros2, rviz, control, ros-humble

I am trying to reset model position at a specific condition in ros2 humble. I found "/gazebo_msgs/srv/SetModelState" would be helpful in resetting position but it is not available when I run "ros2 service list". Any other alternative to reset position would also be helpful.
**NOTE: I want to reset position and not re-spawn the entire robot.**

**UPDATE:**
The robot is stuck at line 12, "Service not available, waiting..." even though "/gazebo/set_entity_state" service is available when running "ros2 service list".

Is there any logical error or I need to import something else in place of "from gazebo_msgs.srv import SetModelState"?

```
from gazebo_msgs.srv import SetModelState

class SetP(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('model_reseter')

        # Create client for SetModelState service
        self.client = self.create_client(SetModelState, '/gazebo/get_entity_state')

        # Wait for service to be available
        while not self.client.wait_for_service(timeout_sec=1.0):
            self.get_logger().info('Service not available, waiting...')

        # Create request message
        request = SetModelState.Request()
        request.model_state.model_name = 'simple_car'
        request.model_state.pose.position.x = 10.5  # Set desired position
        request.model_state.pose.position.y = 0.0
        request.model_state.pose.position.z = 0.0
        request.model_state.pose.orientation.x = 0.0  # Set desired orientation
        request.model_state.pose.orientation.y = 0.0
        request.model_state.pose.orientation.z = 0.0
        request.model_state.pose.orientation.w = 1.0
        request.model_state.twist = Twist()  # Optional: Set desired twist

    def reset_pos(self):
        # Call the service
        future = self.client.call_async(self.request)
        rclpy.spin_until_future_complete(self, future)
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you have to add it to your gazebo world file. See [this answer here](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/29310/gazebo-get-model-state-in-ros2-not-present).

Comment: After adding the line to world file, the service is available in "ros2 service list". But the robot is stuck at line 12(code is updated in the question), "Service not available, waiting..." even though "/gazebo/set_entity_state" service is available when running "ros2 service list". 

Is there any logical error or I need to import something else in place of "from gazebo_msgs.srv import SetModelState"?

Comment: `/gazebo/get_entity_state` needs `gazebo_msgs/GetEntityState`, but I think you need the other service `/gazebo/set_entity_state` instead.